# Import of LESS variables in Rails 3

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, less

I have a global.less file in my assets folder where I've defined many site-wide variables.

To use these variables in other less files, I currently put this at the top of each file:

```
@import 'global';
```

This loads everything fine, but now I have a copy of global loaded into each and every less file. I'm wondering if there is a way to write the import just once in the project, and have the other less files be able to access it?

Answer (score 3):

There are just two small things you need to do to make this happen.

1. Make `application.css` a .less file by renaming it to `application.less` or `application.css.less`.
2. Remove the `require_tree .` sprocket directive, which would import the files in the stylesheets directory on its own, removing your ability to define the order.

Once those things are done, it should work as you expect, simply:

```
// in global.less
@foo: #FFFFFF;

// in foo.less
.foo {
  background-color: @foo;
}

// and finally in application.less
@import 'global';
@import 'foo';
```

Comment: But i see a problem in this practice. Many times, we need make use of 'require tree .' and 'require_self'. In this example, these methods not will are available because you used a .sass file instead a .css. Then is necessary make a '@import' in each action stylesheet.

Comment: No.  The point here is that this method ditches `require_tree` in favor of less's own `@import` functionality, which creates a global namespace keeping mixins and variables available, whereas sprockets' `require` does not.  Note that this question is for less, and *not* sass as you mention, but the same principle applies to both.  See [this note](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#important-note) regarding the issue on sass's github.